# Length of Longest Increasing Subsequence with at most K deletions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy, lis

The input is a list of integers and an integer k. The output has to be the length of the longest possible increasing subsequence of contiguous elements(neighbor elements, for example in '1 0 2' 1 and 2 cannot be part of the same subsequence).

I managed to do better with Greedy, but a couple of cases were quite harsh:

1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8

1

output - 8 (with one 4 deleted, we get '3 4 5 6 7 8')

1 2 3 4 5 0 5 6 7 3

5

output - 7 (1..7)

Can you help me understand what rules should the algorithm respect to succeed?

I am working in Python.

I managed to do good with Greedy, but a couple of cases were quite harsh..

With Dynamic Programming I tried a 2D array, one for each element and k more rows, so dp[i][j] shows the best until position i and with j deletions.

Comment: Your question lacks focus and detail. Focus on one aspect, ask one specific question and provide the relevant code. Delete the repeted informations. Don't use link or image for the code, use a [mcve]

Comment: Are there any constraints on either the length of the input or the range of integers in it?

Comment: @Dave there are no constraints, I am programming in Python. It is pretty though actually haha

Comment: You don't even explain what `k` is supposed to do.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's in the title. There are at most k deletions.

Comment: Please add the code for which you have a question about.